# Prove that the linear isomorphism $T_0$ form $X/\ker(T)$ to $T(X)$ such that $T_0(x+\ker(T))$ = $T(x)$, $\|T_0\|$ = $\|T\|$.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, quotient-spaces

Here is the question:

Suppose $T$ is a bounded linear operator from Banach space $X$ to Banach space $Y$.
Prove that if $T_0$ is the natural linear isomorphism form $X/\ker(T)$ to $T(X)$ such that $T_0(x+\ker(T))$ = $T(x)$  $\forall$ $x \in X$, then $\|T_0\|$ = $\|T\|$.

---

I would like to know how to prove $\|T_0\| \le \|T\|$. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $y \in \ker (T)$ we have  $$\|T_0(x+\ker (T)\|=\|Tx\|=\|T(x+y)\|\leq \|T\| \|x+y\|.$$ Taking infimum over all $y \in \ker(T)$ finishes the proof.

Comment: I see. I didn't use the definition of kernel. Thank you very much.